# Does uniformization theorem imply all 2d manifolds are confromally flat?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, complex-manifolds

[image: Uniformization theorem]

Here is a screenshot from nakahara. Now, to me it looks like that the uniformization theorem implies that all 2d manifolds are conformally flat, because the constant curvature metrics described in (14.119) are conformally flat. Is my conclusion correct ?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the constant 2d curvature metrics are *locally* conformally equivalent (so conformally flat if you wish), but the closed 2d manifolds are not all globally conformally flat. You can see this for instance from the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem, which tells us that the total curvature of a closed 2-manifold is (proportional to) the Euler characteristic. So in particular spheres and surfaces of genus $g \ge 2$ can never carry a global flat metric. 
There is a concept in low-dimensional topology of a Euclidean cone metric, which is a singular metric on a high genus surface which is almost flat except for some cone points where all of the negative curvature has been concentrated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by locally conformally equivalent ? Do you mean to say that the constant curvature metrics in 14.119 are only valid in some small open patch of the manifold ?

Comment: Check the definition of “conformally flat,” though. We're not saying that the manifold admits a flat metric.

Comment: Ah I see, "conformally flat" is what I would have thought to call "locally conformally flat". To user44690, I would say that two metrics $g$ and $g'$ on $M$ are conformally equivalent if there is some $u \in C^\infty(M)$ such that $ug = g'$, i.e. the metrics are equivalent up to some smooth scaling.